# presentation of .htaccess dialog

Tags: html, .htaccess

I am using .htaccess to provide access to a password protected section of my web site. Is it possible to incorporate the process in an html page which is more presentable than the standard dialog box?

Answer (score 1):

It's kinda possible but there is some JavaScript trickery I believe can be done however if you are using **Apache 2.4** you can use a module called `mod_auth_form` to give an HTML friendly alternative.

> This module allows the use of an HTML login form to restrict access by
>   looking up users in the given providers. HTML forms require
>   significantly more configuration than the alternatives, however an
>   HTML login form can provide a much friendlier experience for end
>   users.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_form.html

So if you haven't upgraded, now is the time. :)

Comment: I am using Apache 2.4.12 so will investigate. Thanks